# having different voltages from 2 batteries in serie (3 voltages...)

Tags: voltage, batteries

for a project, running on battery, I need 3 different voltages (+/-3V and 6V)

- +/-3V for OpAmp and µC (attiny85 will be plug to the 3v)
- 6V for the actuator

I was thinking about using 2x CR123 (3V lithium battery) in serie. Doing so, I can use them in a split rail configuration... But what about the 6V ?!

In deed, to control my actuator, I wish to use a DRV8838 (from TI) with the VM pin to 6V ... But .. their is only one ground pin... would it work if i use the -3V as ground ref?
- Or should I found a such a driver but with 2 ground pins (one for the signal, the other for power)
- Or should I reconsider the power supply section entirely using 1x CR223 and something else to split it into +/-3V ?!

I'm a bit confused so I hope I'm clear enough..
Anyway thank you for reading and Thank you again if you can put me out of this :)

Comment: What is the actuator? What are the requirments for its input? Is the input analog or digital?

Comment: The actuator is a simple latching solenoid : 6VDC 400mA (2.4W)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, you need 3 batteries - it's just a question of where ground is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOgKrF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Be warned though that CR2032 batteries can only supply very small currents.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I hope I could also use a charging pompe that i can activate or deactivated whenever i need the +/-3V. And so stay with only 2 batteries and not 3.

Comment: I would be a little worried with this setup. The actuator will be drawing high currents from BAT1 and BAT2. This means your cells will be out of balance after some use without a balancing circuit.